# Real Analysis Homeomophism and 3rd degree polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, polynomials

p(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c, show that p is a homeomorphism if and only if a^2 =< 3b. The inverse homeomorphism f = p^(-1) is derivable if and only if a^2 < 3b.

This question bugs me out, the first part I understand as should be injective so must be only one real root, but since the conjugation of (x-y)^3 = x^3 -3x^2y + 3xy^2 -y^3, how could a^2 < 3b?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't think this is correct. $x^{3}+x$ is a homeomorphism but $1^{2} \leq 0$ is false.

Comment: Sorry It's  p(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c, not p(x) = x^3 + ax + bx + c, already corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to itself is a homeomoprhism then it is strictly increasing. Since our function is a smooth function this gives $p'(x) \geq 0$ for ll $x$. If the quadratic form $3x^{2}+2ax+b$ is non-negative for all $x$ then $a^{2} \leq 3b$. Conversely if $a^{2} \leq 3b$ then $p'(x) >0$ for all $x$ except possible for one value of $x$. This implies that $p$ is injective. Note that $p$ is always surjective: it is a continuous function and $p(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$,$p(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$. This proves the first part.

For the second part you only need the addtional condition that $p'(p^{-1}(x)) \neq 0$ for all $x$. Equivalently we need $p'(y) \neq 0$ for all $y$. Going back  to the quadratic form $p'$ we see that the extra condition we need is $a^{2} \neq 3b$.

Comment: thanks! I figure out the second part in the mean time, but the first one I was analysing in the incorrect manner.